# How do we know when the testng report file (index.html) is finished to be generated?

Tags: testng

I try to transfer automatically the testng results file (*index.html*) via SFTP on a server when all tests are executed (*onExecutionFinish*) but the transferred file is the **previous report** and not the current test report.

```
public void onExecutionFinish() {

     sendViaSFTP(src, dest);
```

}

which Listener do I have to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onExecutionFinish -  Invoked once all the suites have been run

After this the reporters are invoked to generate reports.  However the order of the reporters are not gauranteed.
AFAIK there is no way to ftp the report since testng would exit after generating reports.

Probably, you can consider jenkins to set up the ftp part as a post build step.

Other way is to invoke testng programmatically, in which case you have control from code to decide what happens after testng finishes execution.